# Android application action bar not showing on 4.3 version

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been trying out an application I made and the action bar works on my 4.4 version. The action bar doesn't show on the 4.3 version.

This is what I'm using:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

**This is my Activity Code:**

```
private static final int ABOUTUS = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private static final int CLOSE = Menu.FIRST + 2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
menu.add(Menu.NONE, ABOUTUS, Menu.NONE, "About Us");
menu.add(Menu.NONE, CLOSE, Menu.NONE, "Exit");

return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case ABOUTUS:
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutUs.class);
startActivity(intent);
break;
case CLOSE:
finish();
break;

default:
finish();
break;
}
return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

}
```

I have **appcompat-v7** imported in my workspace.

Not really sure why this is happening but any help received will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're entering dangerous territory when using the preview SDK to ship applications <= lvl 20. Bugs are guaranteed to come up.

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to say

Comment: What Niek means to say is that API level 20+ is still a preview release and not a stable API recommended for production development. It is mainly a technology demonstrator for devs to test their apps with and as such plenty of bugs are bound show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in the activities that use the AppCompat ActionBar you need to import the necessary classes.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; //if you need to customize the ActionBar
```

Secondly, each *activity* must extend the ActionBarActivity class.

```
//say
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

Thirdly, you need to declare the right theme in the *styles.xml* files in the various **values**/**values-v11** folders.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
```

For *styles.xml* in **values-v14** folder :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

If you have done things this way already, then I would like to add that the basic template created using the *New -> Other -> Android -> Android Application Project* option [in Eclipse/ADT] and setting the android:minSdkVersion="8" works well with Android 4.3 on the emulator and on devices. I have tested this and suggest you use this as a reference.

Comment: thakns alot my friend i will test it